# Implement a server component in Next.js that dynamically changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to implement a component in Next.js that shows two different texts based on the minutes of time, even minutes to show "Hi", odds minutes to show "Hello". But not in a client component, but in a server component.

I tried:

```
// ./components/MyComponent.jsx

const Component = ({ data }) => {
  return <>
    {new Date().getMinutes() % 2 === 0 ? "Hi" : "Hello"}
  </>
}

export default Component
```

```
// ./layouts/PostLayout.tsx

import MyComponentfrom '@/components/MyComponent.jsx'
// ..

export default function PostLayout({ content, authorDetails, next, prev, children }: LayoutProps) {
  // ..
  
  return (
    <>
      // ..
      <MyComponent data={""} />
      // ..
    <>
  )
}
// ..
```

but it seems the above calculates the value only the one time on the build time (I guess) and it only shows either "Hi" or "Hello" regardless of the minutes of time I reloaded the page.

So how can I it to work? (Note that I cannot use 'use client' because the delay time is crucial in the app)

```
// versions
"next": "13.5.6",
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-rendering, maybe try passing datetime in searchParams

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't be an option. Needing to add a change on the every URL is too invasive and breaks the whole structure of the application. Completing within the server side is ideal and mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Next.js caches static pages, so you need to opt out of caching.

If you know what page the component is used on, you could include the [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic) `dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` in your `page.jsx`:

```
// page.jsx

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export default function Page() {
  return <PostLayout />
}
```

Alternatively, a [server component can be switched to dynamic rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#switching-to-dynamic-rendering) by either using `cookies()` or `headers()` or using the [unstable `noStore()` method](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore):

```
// ./component/MyComponent.jsx
import { cookies, headers } from 'next/headers'
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache'

const Component = ({ data }) => {
  let _ = cookies();
  // or
  let _ = headers();
  // or
  noStore();

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The cookies() way worked for me. But does that mean disabling the advantage of SSG entirely because of a single component, and is for now a best workaround (impossible to be more performance friendly), am I correct? 
Since I need to put the component on the every single page of the app, just because of the one component the almost entire app turns out to SSR from SSG, that's kind of sad for me so if possible in any way I'd like to avoid.

Comment: As far as I know, currently, that's true. But they are working on [Partial Pre-Rendering](https://vercel.com/blog/partial-prerendering-with-next-js-creating-a-new-default-rendering-model) which should fix this in the future.